# Update product but lose image of product ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I working on CRUD of Product. My problem is when I update any product and not import the image, its lose all the image of product. Here my controller method `Edit` of `Product`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null || _context.Products== null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);

    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(product);
}

// POST: Admin/Products/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
// For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit(int id, Product product)
{
    if (id != product.Id)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    
    string uniqueFileName1 = GetProfilePhotoFileName1(product);
    product.Image1 = uniqueFileName1;
    string uniqueFileName2 = GetProfilePhotoFileName2(product);
    product.Image2 = uniqueFileName2;
    string uniqueFileName3 = GetProfilePhotoFileName3(product);
    product.Image3 = uniqueFileName3;
    string uniqueFileName4 = GetProfilePhotoFileName4(product);
    product.Image4 = uniqueFileName4;

    _context.Update(product);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return View(product);
}
```

I want if I update the product but not import any new images they will be the same images when I created. But now when I click edit and save its just lose all the url of img in database.

Here my view of edit:

[edit view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAc9z.png)

Does anyone know the problem and how to fix it? Many thanks guys for reading

Comment: You want to validate your image input, if there are no images then skip assigning anything image related to your `Product`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap a conditional around the code that overrides the images, checking whether the first image was set. If so, do the overriding. Ignore it if not.

```
// POST: Admin/Products/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
// For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit(int id, Product product)
{
    if (id != product.Id)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    string image1 = GetProfilePhotoFileName1(product);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(image1)) {
        string uniqueFileName1 = image1;
        product.Image1 = uniqueFileName1;
        string uniqueFileName2 = GetProfilePhotoFileName2(product);
        product.Image2 = uniqueFileName2;
        string uniqueFileName3 = GetProfilePhotoFileName3(product);
        product.Image3 = uniqueFileName3;
        string uniqueFileName4 = GetProfilePhotoFileName4(product);
        product.Image4 = uniqueFileName4;
    }

    _context.Update(product);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return View(product);
}
```

EDIT

The code above presumes that there is no second image if there was no first image and so on. If this presumption is reliable, then the code is correct. If the user may set an image which is not the first, then we will need to check them all for being null or empty, like

```
if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(image1) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(image2) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(image3) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(image4))) {
    //...
}
```

with the images being precomputed.

One could bring this to the next level via:

```
public static bool AllNull(params string[] strings)
{
    return strings.All(s => s == null);
}
```

and then do

```
if (!SomeStringExtension::AllNull(image1, image2, image3, image4)) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: And what if the user puts an image in `Image2` but not in `Image1`? You can't rely on users not misusing things and not using them as expected.

Comment: @Peppermintology thanks for your comment. Basically I presumed that if there is no first image, then there is no second, third or fourth image either. If this presumption is reliable, then my code is correct. If not, then we need to check for the nullness/emptyness of the other images as well, like you suggested. I have edited my answer in order to provide info for that case.

Comment: We can never and should never, presume anything when it comes to how end users will utilise something. :)

Comment: @Peppermintology I presumed that the system does not allow a second image to be uploaded if there wasn't a first. I did not presume that it's allowed and the user will not do it. If the system does not allow you to upload a second image or a third or a fourth if you didn't upload your first, then the original logic is enough.

Comment: I get that, not sure you're getting my point which is _do not presume_.

Comment: @Peppermintology I completely understood you. My point is that if there is no second image if there was no first, then my original answer is correct. I have added info for the case when that's not true into my answer.